# Texture loading

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx and I am loading all my textures as shown below,

```
Texture objTexture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("imagename"));
```

This code was inside my ApplicationListener. But, I want to load all my images at the start of my game. I don't want to load them inside of ApplicationListener. I have tried accessing texture object outside the scope of OpenGL and failed. Can anyone suggest me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the soonest you can load those textures (it involves uploading them into the VRAM, so I guess that the Graphics module has to be initialized and all the GL stuff done) is in the `create` function of the `ApplicationListener`.

Also, you may consider using the new `AssetManager` to manage your resources. Or write a simpler asset manager.

Comment: ,thank you for your answer. But the thing is,in libgdx we can load textures through filehandle, pixmap etc., i have loaded the images using them outside the scope of ApplicationListener, but iam not getting the images on the screen. The screen was completely turned to white.If i write them in the create of ApplicationListener, every time the images are getting loaded, even while shifiting from one level to another level.

Comment: Sorry... So, you load the image data outside the scope of the ApplicationListener, and can't compose a Texture (upload it to the VRAM) with it? What about copying the raw bytes to a Pixmap and then creating a Texture with it? Have you tried to ask this question in http://badlogicgames.com/forum/?

Comment: i have copied the raw bytes to a  pixmap, but there is no much difference in the performance. And how to load the textures into VRAM, i have no idea about it.Can you help me with any link or tutrial.And i haven't posed my question in the forum.

Comment: From my limited knowledge, I think that it is in the constructor of `Texture` where it 'uploads' the data into the video memory using the proper GL instructions. So I would say that a `new Texture(pixmap)` copies it into the VRAM. `Pixmap` doesn't deal with GL, afaik.

Comment: And try with the forum, there are many competent persons there... :D

Comment: thank you, as part of my trial, pixmap too deals with GL. I will watch out the forum.Thanks alot again.

Comment: Well, by 'deal' I meant that I don't see any GL commands per se in the Pixmap object, at least not in Gdx2DPixmap.java and Pixmap.java. And all the operations on a Pixmap (blitting onto another Pixmap, drawing on a Pixmap, et cetera) are implemented in C (see the jni folder), and are operations where GL is not used, just classic manipulation of the array of pixels. Anyway, good luck with it!